# Track limit on SoundCloud custom player?

Tags: soundcloud

My custom player at woofdriver.com only shows the first 50 of my SoundCloud account's 81 tracks. How can I get the full list to display in the player? I see some references to "limit", but only in the context of the API.

I'm using this custom player http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player and the following code to invoke it on the page. The player works great, but it just shows the first 50 tracks instead of the 81 in my stream at http://soundcloud.com/williamhelman,

```
$("a.wooftraxplayer").scPlayer({
  autoPlay  :   false
});
```

Comment: could you provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got a response back from SoundCloud on this. When you use just the base URL for the account, it limits to 50 with the custom player. However, if you create a set, there is no such limit. So, using http://soundcloud.com/williamhelman/sets/woofdriverhits as my URL, I now get all of the tracks in the list.

Comment: how would i limit the sc-custom player to say 5 tracks?

Answer (score 0):

it seams the custom player has a limit and i dont know the way around it, but maybe you can use the new stylish Widget!!

try going to the [SoundCloud Widget API Playground](http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html)

and entering the url:
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/williamhelman

i get more than 80 songs in the player and it has some nice features like

hope this helps